# No me funciona npm run watch

Tags: laravel, laravel-mix

Tengo npm version 6.9.0
Node 10.16.0
Larave 5.6.39

Me meto al proyecto y puedo ejecutar sin problema el comando npm run dev, pero el comando npm run watch se ejecuta, aparece una serie de carga de archivos y queda ahí en pausa sin arrojar un error. Este es lo que arroja después de ejecutar el comando npm run watch.

¿Como puedo resolver este problema?

[image: Captura-de-Pantalla-2019-06-21-a-la-s-16-16-41.png]

Comment: pero te dice que compiló correctamente. run watch no se va a detener hasta que tú lo detengas (con ctrl+c por ejemplo). acaso no refleja los cambios que haces?

Comment: antes de eso. Qué quieres lograr ejecutando el **run watch**? o por qué necesitas ejecutar ese comando?

Answer (score 1):

En algunos sistemas no funciona `npm run watch`, me ha ocurrido en varias ocasiones, sin embargo, en dichos casos el comando alternativo siempre me ha funcionado:

```
npm run watch-poll
```

Hasta ahora no ha existido una razón clara sobre por qué no funciona npm run watch en algunos sistemas.